# How to create dynamic variable names for ExtJS objects?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I am trying to create

```
window1 = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
```

then

```
window2 = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
```

and so on

I want them to be created in the `for` loop that I already have but the standart dynamic variable names for JavaScript didn't work, probably because it wants me to write `new` or may be something to do with global scope, I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really clear what you are asking, what's wrong with:

```js
var myWindows = {};
for(var i=0; i<10; i++)
    myWindows['win'+i] = Ext.create('Ext.Window', { /* ... */ });
```

```js
console.log( myWindows.win1 === myWindows['win'+1] ) // true
```

*see: [Object Access Notation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4968448/1238344)*